# Ubuntu 18.04 loosing USB-C displays & USB devices

Tags: 18.04, usb, display, thunderbolt, usb-c

So I have the following setup - Alienware m15 R3 with two Dell U2719DC displays (first display is feeding the other via display port/MST) attached via USB-C/Thunderbolt 3 port. First of the displays (which feeds the other one and is connected to the laptop via USB-C) has two devices attached to the USB hub that is built into it - a keyboard and a mouse. What happens that at a random time (or because of a trigger?) the displays start shutting down and if I replug them they shutdown in a couple of seconds or even don't come up at all. I've noticed that the process sometimes starts when launching Android emulator (that starts severe on/off cycle), `lspci`/`lswh` trigger a single on/off cycle, some times at a random point. I tried to gather logs with `tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}` during this on/off madness. I consistently see (a lot of these):

```
Feb  3 20:11:27 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5918.379945] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: Intel SPT PCH root port ACS workaround enabled
Feb  3 20:11:28 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5919.648785] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Feb  3 20:11:28 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5919.648790] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
```

After some of them (around 70%) I have notifications about usb devices being disconnected:

```
Feb  3 20:12:24 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5975.820361] usb 1-11: USB disconnect, device number 10
Feb  3 20:12:24 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5975.820362] usb 1-11.1: USB disconnect, device number 11
```

When everything comes up again it seems that yeah these devices are the usb hub in the display, the keyboard and mouse (`1-11.1` and `1-11.2` respectively):

```
 3 20:12:06 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5957.323800] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
Feb  3 20:12:06 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5957.748121] usb 1-11: New USB device found, idVendor=0451, idProduct=8442, bcdDevice= 1.00
Feb  3 20:12:06 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5957.748127] usb 1-11: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
Feb  3 20:12:06 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5957.748131] usb 1-11: SerialNumber: E4010869A2EA
Feb  3 20:12:06 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5957.749738] hub 1-11:1.0: USB hub found
Feb  3 20:12:06 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5957.749786] hub 1-11:1.0: 6 ports detected
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.039762] usb 1-11.1: new full-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.141685] usb 1-11.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1532, idProduct=005c, bcdDevice= 2.00
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.141691] usb 1-11.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.141694] usb 1-11.1: Product: Razer DeathAdder Elite
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.141697] usb 1-11.1: Manufacturer: Razer
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.462582] usb 1-11.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c339, bcdDevice=13.00
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.462583] usb 1-11.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.462584] usb 1-11.2: Product: Pro Gaming Keyboard
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.462585] usb 1-11.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
Feb  3 20:12:07 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5958.462586] usb 1-11.2: SerialNumber: 086B367A3231
```

While everything is running, the output of `lspci -tv` is:

```
rudolfs@rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3:~$ lspci -tv
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Device 9b54
           +-01.0-[01-03]----00.0-[02-03]----00.0-[03]--+-00.0  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 7340
           |                                            \-00.1  Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device ab38
           +-01.1-[04]--
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation Device 9bc4
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
           +-12.0  Intel Corporation Device 06f9
           +-13.0  Intel Corporation Device 06fc
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation Device 06ed
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation Device 06ef
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation Device 06e8
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation Device 06e0
           +-1b.0-[05-3d]----00.0-[06-3d]--+-00.0-[07]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
           |                               +-01.0-[08-3c]--
           |                               \-02.0-[3d]----00.0  Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
           +-1b.4-[3e]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
           +-1d.0-[3f]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM951/PM951
           +-1d.4-[40]----00.0  SK hynix Device 1339
           +-1d.6-[41]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 3000
           +-1d.7-[42]----00.0  Intel Corporation Device 2723
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation Device 068d
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation Device 06c8
           +-1f.4  Intel Corporation Device 06a3
           \-1f.5  Intel Corporation Device 06a4
```

output of `lsusb -tv` is:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/8p, 10000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 5: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 17, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Did a lot of googling before writing this up, so relevant stuff I've seen mentioned:

- Thunderbolt security is off in BIOS
- `bolt` package is installed
- Nothing shows up in the Devices/Thunderbolt panel, but I assume that is fine, since none of the attached devices (2 monitors, keyboard and mouse) is actually a Thunderbolt device?

There were some mentions of thunderbolt ports going to sleep if inactive - so I cannot understand if the USB hub on the other end (in the display) is supposed to keep them alive or not?
This issue is supper annoying since I actually need to use the Android emulator, but running it makes the machine unusable. Any advices, suggestions? I can provide any other needed info.

Not sure if that is relevant to the issue, but I have and unknown device in the Ubuntu software settings (I assume it is the Killer Wireless card, even though wifi works).[image: Unknown Intel Device]

Actually just noticed that there are single blocks of these errors:

```
Feb  3 20:12:30 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5981.555749] usb 1-11: new high-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
Feb  3 20:12:30 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5981.638519] usb 4-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb  3 20:12:30 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5981.683827] usb 1-11: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb  3 20:12:31 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5981.850723] usb 4-1: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb  3 20:12:31 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5981.891708] usb 1-11: Device not responding to setup address.
Feb  3 20:12:31 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5982.055666] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
Feb  3 20:12:31 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5982.099676] usb 1-11: device not accepting address 14, error -71
```

and:

```
Feb  3 20:12:35 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5986.151734] usb usb4-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Feb  3 20:12:35 rudolfs-Alienware-m15-R3 kernel: [ 5986.151820] usb usb4-port1: attempt power cycle
```